# Plotting dots to a map given latitude and longitude

Tags: image, geospatial, datapoint

Summary: I need a tool that can put 60m+ points on a map image. I'm trying to show density map and would like to plot a dot for each point (lat/long) on the map.

Hi I'm working on project that requires a density map. I have latitude and longitude and all the tools that I have seen (Ammap, FusionCharts maps, google charts/map) requires either XML or JSON or some other data type with the data points. Problem here is that, I have 60 million + data points and transferring any type of object with that many data point is not feasible.

One solution I can think of is mapping latitude and longitude to pixels of the map image. That requires a lot of time and work. I was wondering if you guys have done something similar and know of tools that can do this for me. It doesn't have to be free.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be much better off creating a [heatmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map) instead of passing all of the individual points to the map, which would get very busy, very quickly.

There are already a few discussions over at [GIS.StackExchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com) about this exact topic.  Search the the [[heatmap]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heatmap) tag.

Since you mentioned FusionCharts, assuming you can load all of your data into a Google Fusion Table, it looks like you should be able to [make a heat map in Google Fusion Tables](http://www.poynter.org/how-tos/digital-strategies/126628/how-to-make-a-heatmap-in-google-fusion-tables/)).

Comment: I've already created heat map, but it doesn't contain all the information. This is for analysis, and the easiest way I can explain it is via heatmap of population. With heat map you can show that one area is dense vs the other, but if you plot ethnicity with different color, you see not only where the population is dense, but you can also see that different ethnic groups live together and where they are concentrated. This gives much more information in image.